# SQL Management Studio 2014 auto-changing password for login

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an issue where SSMS changes the password of a login after I have created it with a different password, and thus I am not able to log in with this new user, as I am not allowed to view the newly changed password. I looked around online and found no answer to this problem.

Here is a screenshot of password as it appears after being changed by SSMS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF6Kx.png

Comment: It doesn't change it.  The asterisks you see there are masking.  You need to check that you have permissions to alter the sql server user and that sql server users are permitted on the server.  Is the user even present in your db server login list?

You need to provide a lot more information on the steps you have taken and any checks you have done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it cleared up a lot of things. I assume the user is present, since I have it included in the logins folder: http://i.imgur.com/FssJtLY.png
How would I go about checking whether i have permission to alter the SQL server user?

Comment: If you have that much visibility then you likely have permissions.  When you go into the login dialog and change the password and press OK, please confirm you do not get a 'Change password failed for Login 'User1' exception message.

Comment: I tried changing the password for User1 and received no error messages. When i try to log in with this user I receive a '18456' error code from MS SQL server.

Comment: OK next right-click your server > properties > security and confirm the server authentication mode is set to 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode', rather than just 'Windows Authentication mode'

Comment: Thanks, I changed security settings as you said, but I am now receiving a new error: http://i.imgur.com/8wkvONd.png
I am still able to login using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Have you restarted your SQL server service on the machine the database server sits on? (services.msc from the start menu search bar > SqlServer(YourInstance) > Restart the service)

Comment: That did it, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, I have written this up as an answer, please mark it as correct by clicking the tick next to my answer so any other users who see your question know how to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the issue:

1) Select 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode' in Your Server properties >  security > server authentication mode.

2) Restart the instance's SQL Server Service on the machine the instance is running on : Services.msc from the start menu search bar > SqlServer(YourInstance) > Restart the service

See comments on question for troubleshooting steps.